# joint density problem from P1 probability actuary book - solving density function of the subtraction of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be two random variables with joint density function $$f_{XY} $$.
Compute the pdf of $$ U = Y − X $$

I've looked at this problem multiple times and I keep getting a different answer than the book.

For my joint density function I'm getting the following:

$$f_{Y −X}(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x, a+x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -f_{X,Y}(y-a, y) dy $$

If X and Y are independent I'm getting the following:

$$ f_{Y −X}(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y}(a+x) \cdot f_X(x) dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -f_{X}(y-a) \cdot f_Y(y) dy $$

The book gives this answer:

$$ f_{Y −X}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y} (y − a, y)dy $$ Moreover, the book says If X and Y are independent then
$$  f_{Y −X}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(y − a)f_Y (y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(y)f_Y (a + y)dy $$

would anyone kindly explain how the book got this answer and am I wrong? I was simply following the same approach as if we were to calculate $$ U = X+Y $$ but it seems something is really off with my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the minus signs and you are correct:

$$f_{Y −X}(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x, a+x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(y-a, y) dy $$

If X and Y are independent:

$$ f_{Y −X}(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y}(a+x) \cdot f_X(x) dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(y-a) \cdot f_Y(y) dy $$

This is consistent with what the book says, and with the fact that pdf's must be positive.

---

Let us prove the second one : $f_{Y −X}(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(y-a, y) dy$. I highlight in bold what I suspect you might have gotten wrong.

Let $h$ be any positive measurable function.

We use the definition of density and Fubini's theorem to obtain

$$E[h(Y-X)] = \int_{\Bbb R^2} h(y-x) f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y-x) f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx\right) dy$$
Now we perform the change of variables  $a=y-x$ in the inner integral, with $dx = -da$.
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} -h(a) f_{X,Y}(y-a,y) dx\right)dy$$
Now **a minus sign has appeared but at the same time the bounds of integration have been reversed**. We put them back in the correct order.
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(a) f_{X,Y}(y-a,y) dx\right)dy$$
Fubini again
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(a)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(y-a,y) dy\right)da$$
So the thing inside the parenthesis is $f_{Y-X}(a)$ QED.

Comment: thank you this really helped me understand where I went wrong... I was forgetting to use the chain rule when it came to $$ F'(y-a) $$ differentiating in respect to $$ a $$... not sure why you needed Fubini's theorem or use of Expectation... Simply differentiating $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -F_{X,Y}(Y-a) dy$$ in respects to $$ a $$ yields $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(Y-a) dy $$ and similarly differentiating $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -F_{X}(Y-a) f_Y dy$$ yields $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(Y-a) f_Y dy$$ If variables are independent.

Comment: Right, this works also. My change of variables method is more general and allows to compute the distribution of for more complicated expressions of $X$ and $Y$, or even, using multivariate change of variables, the joint distribution of a pair of expressions.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks @justt I accepted thr answer... I'm still trying to see why the use of expectation would be helpful for more complex functions... I'll research this a bit more